# SQL/MySQL: Retrieve active article from table with 3 columns (Old | New | Date)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to retrieve the active article from the following example table:

```
Example Table       
Old Article | New Article| Substitution Date
A             B            01-01-2012
B             C            01-02-2012
C             B            01-03-2012
C             A            01-04-2012

 Desired Output     
Old Article | New Article   
B             A 
C             A
```

Is it possible within mysql/sql? Thanks in advance as I've been struggling with this for a while.

(Note: the actual table has more than 200k rows)

Comment: why new article A , A?

Comment: i think [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a85b/10) is close but not 100% sure on it

Comment: echo_me that would solve only the last level of relation, if you had the following inser into and run the query example of your link you'll see that the result skips one desired row output -> insert into foo (o, n, d) values ('a', 'd', '2012-01-05');

Answer (score 0):

You're better off having another table that keeps the list of 'current' articles.  Whenever you replace an article, update the current table, but also update this new table with mappings of all articles that are being replaced.  The new table would be identical in schema to your current one.  When you do the replacement, you would: update [table_name] set new_article = [newest article], substitution_date=[now] where new_article = [article being replaced].

Comment: That would be fine if there were only 1 chain of relationships with only one article but the actual dataset has multiple relations. At this moment I need to retrieve all the active articles.

Comment: If you have, for any 'Old Article,' only 0 or 1 'New Article' entries, you keep your original table for whenever you want to retrieve the entire chain of replacements, but to have quick access to the top of the replacement stack for any article, you create this new table which simply maps an 'Old Article' to the last 'New Article' in its replacement chain.  If you're doing a lot of lookups, particularly if your chains get deep, the one-table solution is going to be computationally expensive where the one I'm suggesting is a simple lookup.